# What is StarterTemplateAppListenerHost in Service Satck?

Tags: servicestack

I am doing some stuff in Service Stack self host in windows service. The [link](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Examples/blob/master/src/StarterTemplates/WinServiceAppHost/Program.cs) gave me some hint. But in the code, what is StarterTemplateAppListenerHost then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a class which extends `AppHostHttpListenerBase` ([Source here](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Examples/blob/master/src/StarterTemplates/StarterTemplates.Common/StarterTemplateAppHost.cs)) which is used to provide the http listener and application configuration.

```cs
public class StarterTemplateAppListenerHost : AppHostHttpListenerBase
{
    static readonly IAppSettings AppSettings = new AppSettings();

    public StarterTemplateAppListenerHost() 
        : base(AppSettings.GetString("ServiceName") ?? "StarterTemplate HttpListener", typeof(HelloService).Assembly) { }

    public override void Configure(Funq.Container container)
    {
        container.Register(new TodoRepository());
    }
}
```

This is demonstrated also [in the official documentation here](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Self-hosting#complete-c-console-host-example).

---

> I just wonder why the link doesn't have OnStart() etc

The example has two different compilation modes. When it's run in `debug`, it will not run as a service, and solely uses `StarterTemplateAppListenerHost`.

When it is run in `release` mode then it will create a service around the instance of `StarterTemplateAppListenerHost`. The [`WinService` class](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Examples/blob/master/src/StarterTemplates/WinServiceAppHost/WinService.cs) provides the `OnStart` and `OnStop` methods which are expected of Windows Services by extending [`System.ServiceProcess.ServiceBase`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.servicebase%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

---

So to get it running as a Windows Service you will need to include these 3 files:

- [Program.cs](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Examples/blob/master/src/StarterTemplates/WinServiceAppHost/Program.cs)
- [WinService.cs](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Examples/blob/master/src/StarterTemplates/WinServiceAppHost/WinService.cs)
- [StarterTemplateAppListenerHost.cs](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Examples/blob/master/src/StarterTemplates/StarterTemplates.Common/StarterTemplateAppHost.cs)

Comment: What is "HelloService"? Is it another windows service? But I already created one by https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Examples/blob/master/src/StarterTemplates/WinServiceAppHost/Program.cs. And what is "TodoRespository"?

Comment: @Love They are simply other examples. Some of the examples share a common code. The best way to get a self hosted is to follow the instructions here https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Self-hosting

Comment: -@Scott, I will. I just wonder why the link doesn't have OnStart() etc. should I combine two examples together?

Comment: @Love I have updated the answer to address the `OnStart` method.

Comment: -@Scott, your first link "Program.cs" is same as the third link "StartTemplateApplistenerHost.cs". I am confused. And which one is the startup item?

Comment: @Love I have fixed that link.

Comment: -@Scott, I got it, so how about TodoRepository, is it a new class I have to write by myself? So it will contain "PUT,POST,GET..." request and response etc?

Comment: @Love I think you should read through [the official documentation](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Create-your-first-webservice) first. It will teach you how to set up a basic service from scratch step by step, then you can add the Windows Service around it. But you are right the TodoRepository will contain the rest actions and your service routes.